# Emergency information in Android N

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Based on this [link](http://www.androidauthority.com/emergency-info-android-n-679061/) it seems that Android N is coming up with a new feature that will let users build a medical profile which can be used by medical professionals in case of an emergency.
So, I've been searching around a lot but I cannot find any references to whether developers will be able to pull this information from the device. I guess it would be part of [Google's People API](https://developers.google.com/people/), but right now I cannot find any references to this.
So, does anyone have any ideas whether this is possible or not? And if possible is there any documentation pointing towards it?

Comment: Why do you need that information? That would be a violation of privacy

Comment: @TimCastelijns: If I'm building a medical app that needs all this information instead of asking the user to input all this data again, we could just pull it from his device. Also, it wouldn't be a violation of privacy if we ask for the right permissions and the user accepts them.

Comment: @rashmi1412 did you find any way around?